# Simplify statement using the laws and axioms of logic.

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I am trying to do logic expression simplification using boolean algebra laws and axioms of logic, but I don't understand it at all. I attempt the question and this is what i have come up with.

the is the question giving :
(¬a∨b)∧(a∨b)∧¬a

and this is what i got:

= (¬a∨b)∧(a∨b)∧¬a

= (¬a∨a)∧b)∧¬a  - Distributive

=(¬a∨a)b¬a - Idempotent

=fvb  -Complement or negation

=b identify

can someone please point me to the right direction and explain whats going on. i would be grateful thanks

Comment: Did you mean (¬a∧a)∨b)∧¬a  - Distributive ?

Comment: honestly im not so sure anymore. im so confused now like i am not so sure im looking at. would that make sense tho like if it like (¬a∧a)∨b)∧¬a

Comment: Boolean distributive law is   $ {  x\vee (y\wedge z)=(x\vee y)\wedge (x\vee z)} $

Comment: im not even sure if im answer are right or wrong

Answer (score 1):

You applied distributivity the wrong way.
Following the right distributive law (as JW Tanner points inn a comment) together with the commutative one, you get
$$(a' \vee b) \wedge (a \vee b) \wedge a' = ((a' \wedge a) \vee b) \wedge a'.$$
(Here I'm using $x'$ for your notation $\neg x$).
Since $a' \wedge a = 0$ and $0 \vee b = b$, it all becomes $b \wedge a'$.

---

A different approach would be to use absorption: after using commutativity and associativity, you get
$$(a' \vee b) \wedge (a \vee b) \wedge a' = ((a' \vee b) \wedge a') \wedge (a \vee b).$$
By absorption and distributivity, this gives
$$a' \wedge (a \vee b) = (a' \wedge a) \vee (a' \wedge b) = 0 \vee (a' \wedge b) = a' \wedge b.$$